# What does Captain Kurotsuchi do to Nemu in Bleach Episode 200?

Tags: bleach

What does Captain Kurotsuchi do to bring Nemu back to consciousness after her spirit particles have been absorbed by Szayelaporro?

I remember Ishida saying that it couldn't be aired. what exactly did he do?

You can watch the scene [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7whfxhAqSs).

Comment: good question, but I don't think you will get an answer, unless the manga was more explicit.

Comment: Ahem, ahem. I never thought anyone would have asked this question explicitly. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manga doesn't explicitly state what Mayuri did, and Uryuu makes the same remark.

[image: Uryuu's reaction]

However, it seems very likely that Mayuri fiddled with Nemu's *"reset button"*<sup>1</sup>, based on her moaning (see screenshot below), and his remark:

> You can't even understand something that simple by looking at it?

[image: Nemu moaning]

He later derides Uryuu and Renji for reaching wrong conclusions, and calls them laymen who do not understand his technology. This suggests that he might have given Nemu something *like* a Tantric Massage. Laymen watching it in our world would reach exactly the same wrong conclusion.

[image: Mayuri annoyed at Ishida and Renji]

I know the above theory is a speculation, but this is as much evidence I can provide to support it. I guess we won't know any more of what he did for the reason Uryuu mentions.

---

<sup>1 Sorry, I cannot be more explicit than that. I hope you know what I mean.</sup>

Comment: reset button! Ahem, nice choice of words. :)